# Spring : Adding FlashAttribute in RedirectAttributes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, redirect

I am new in spring and learning `RedirectAttributes`.Below is th sample code I am executing.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public String app(Model model,RedirectAttributes rm) throws IOException{
    UserCO userCO= new UserCO();
    userCO.setEmail("rptdbay@gmail.com");
    rm.addFlashAttribute("flashkey", "flashvalue");
    rm.addFlashAttribute("userCO", userCO);
    return "redirect:/controller1";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/controller1")
public String app1(Model model,HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException{
    System.out.println("=====================================");
    System.out.println("In Controller 1");
    Map md = model.asMap();
    for (Object modelKey : md.keySet()) {
        Object modelValue = md.get(modelKey);
        System.out.println("Model data =="+ modelKey + " -- " + modelValue);
    }

    java.util.Enumeration<String> reqEnum = request.getParameterNames();
    while (reqEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
        String s = reqEnum.nextElement();
        System.out.println("Request data =="+ s+" : "+ request.getParameter(s));
    }


    return "redirect:/controller2";
}



@RequestMapping(value="/controller2")
public String app2(Model model,HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException{
    System.out.println("=====================================");
    System.out.println("In Controller 2");
    Map md = model.asMap();
    for (Object modelKey : md.keySet()) {
        Object modelValue = md.get(modelKey);
        System.out.println("Model data =="+ modelKey + " -- " + modelValue);
    }

    java.util.Enumeration<String> reqEnum = request.getParameterNames();
    while (reqEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
        String s = reqEnum.nextElement();
        System.out.println("Request data =="+ s+" : "+ request.getParameter(s));
    }


    return "redirect:/controller3";
}
```

I have added String `"flashvalue"` and a object of bean `userCO`.I observed that-

1. Both `"flashvalue"` and `userCO` are available in Controller1.
   Fine!,but in Controller2 `"flashvalue"` is available but `userCO`
   not .Why so?
2. In Controller1 data is coming in Model ony but in Controller2 same
   data is availavble in request only.Why so?

Below is my console log.

> =====================================
>
> In Controller 1
>
> Model data ==userCO -- com.ttnd.mvc_mod.co.UserCO@60098260
>
> Model data ==flashkey -- flashvalue
>
> =====================================
>
> In Controller 2
>
> Request data ==flashkey : flashvalue

Is there any other way possible to get `FlashAttribute` rather than binding in `Model`?

Answer (score 0):

First the explanation of your console log: You receive two model objects in controller 1. This is because you specify two flash attributes in method `app`. Flash attributes are stored in the HTTP session for the target controller, which retrieves it from there as model attributes. After that the flash attributes are erased by Spring.

In controller 2 the flash attributes are no longer available. The reason why “flashkey” is available in controller 2 as request attribute is, since primitive types in models are exposed as query parameters to the redirect target. As mentioned before, the flash attributes passed to controller 1 are exposed as model attributes. Your “userCO” is no primitive type, so you it will not get it as request parameter, while you will get “flashkey” as query parameter in controller 2.

If you want to switch off the “forward” of model objects as request parameters, set `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.setIgnoreDefaultModelOnRedirect(boolean)` to true (as suggested by Spring for ‘new’ applications).

I don’t know whether there is another way to get flash attributes. I’d encourage you to not work around the concepts of Spring here but handle the flash attributes just like you did in your question. Think of flash attributes as model attributes in your redirect target. If you – for what reason – need two redirect until you reach your target, add the desired attributes a second time as flash attributes in controller 1.

See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-redirect-attributes and http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-flash-attributes for any details.

Comment: from where this primitive data is coming?I added `return "redirect:/controller2";` only.

Comment: All model attributes available in controller 1 will be added as query parameter to the request to controller 2 (flashkey were introduced to the model by the flash attribute set by the origin request to "/")

Comment: summering my question in short,since `attribute` added either in `RedirectAttributes` or in `model` by `.addAttribute()` is available in request after redirection.correct?so what is the difference in both way?

Comment: Yes this is correct, but with restriction on primitive types. See reference doc for this. It's said there: `By default all model attributes are considered to be exposed as URI template variables in the redirect URL. Of the remaining attributes those that are primitive types or collections/arrays of primitive types are automatically appended as query parameters`. I don't know what you mean with `what is the difference in both way`?

Comment: my concern is `RedirectAttributes.addAttribute("key","val")` and `model.addAttribute("key","val")`.Both are available after redirection as query parameter for primitive or collection of premitives.